# How to Create new table(models) whenever a new record is created in Django without interrupt a running server

Tags: django, django-models

How to  create separate table for each record in models (table with same fields for all models), It should happens whenever the new record in models in aa running server without interruption of server

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Id  |       Station Name     |        GPS Location         |    Address
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

|  1   | Station 1              |   35.211898, -101.969547    |  Some where  |

|  2   | Station 2              |   43.793428, -102.658402    |  Some where  |

|  ... |..............          |  ...................        |  ......      |

|  ... |..............          |  ...................        |  ......      |

|  ... |..............          |  ...................        |  ......      |

|  n   |Station n               |  xx.xxxxxx,  xx.xxxxx       |  xxxxxx      |

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For these each entries I need separate table(Models) like below mentioned should create automatically , whenever a new record is added
All Columns headings(Fields) are same in all the table(models) which are create for the record

```
**TABLE NAME**: Station 1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| TimeStamp              | Temperature | Humidity |...|...|...| 40th Column | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

|14-Jan-18 11:30:12      |     20.13 C |    15%   |...|...|...|    xxxxxx   |

|14-Jan-18 11:30:13      |     20.16 C |    15%   |...|...|...|    xxxxxx   |

|14-Jan-18 11:30:14      |     20.11 C |    15%   |...|...|...|    xxxxxx   |

|14-Jan-18 11:30:15      |     20.18 C |    15%   |...|...|...|    xxxxxx   |

.
.
.

|20-Dec-18 16:14:30      |     30.74 C|     55%  |...|...|...|    xxxxxx    |


**TABLE NAME**: Station 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| TimeStamp              | Temperature | Humidity |...|...|...| 40th Column | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

|20-Jan-18 16:01:56      |     40.13 C |    35%   |...|...|...|    xxxxxx   |

|20-Jan-18 16:01:57      |     40.16 C |    35%   |...|...|...|    xxxxxx   |

|20-Jan-18 16:01:58      |     40.11 C |    35%   |...|...|...|    xxxxxx   |

|20-Jan-18 16:01:59      |     40.18 C |    35%   |...|...|...|    xxxxxx   |

.
.
.

|20-Dec-18 16:14:30      |     20.74 C|     10%  |...|...|...|    xxxxxx    |



**TABLE NAME**: Station n
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| TimeStamp              | Temperature | Humidity |...|...|...| 40th Column | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

|12-Jan-18 21:54:01      |     30.13 C |    45%   |...|...|...|    xxxxxx   |

|12-Jan-18 21:54:02      |     30.16 C |    45%   |...|...|...|    xxxxxx   |

|12-Jan-18 21:54:03      |     30.11 C |    45%   |...|...|...|    xxxxxx   |

|12-Jan-18 21:54:04      |     30.18 C |    45%   |...|...|...|    xxxxxx   |

.
.
.

|26-Dec-18 23:45:30      |     10.40 C|     10%  |...|...|...|    xxxxxx    |
```

Now i am logging all station data in to one TABLE. 
Now there is only 10 stations

Each station will log data for every 1 second

In two to three months it will increase upto 1000 stations.

So 1000's of process will access the single table in the Database for every second
I don't know how much this will work efficiently when scaling to 1000 station.

If user needs to see one year historical data, Then need to Query from the same table,
So  I am afraid how can that table can handle every things.

How long it will take to a Query 1 year of data from database.

So this idea and question arise for me

Currently I am using SQLite database.

Comment: Why would you do this? This isn't how you use a relational database. Just have a single model for the data, with a foreign key to the Station model.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Now there is only 10 stations, At present i am using like as you mentioned but in two to three months it will increase upto     1000 stations. At that time 1000 process will access and log the data to same table. Each Station will log the data in to Database table for every 1 second. I don't know how it is efficient. I am working currently in SQLite+Django.

Comment: Well, for a start sqlite isn't really meant for multiple processes at the same time. But a normal database shouldn't have any trouble. Although I can't see why you need 1000 separate processes in the first place,

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Thanks for editing question. I am new to stackoverflow , python,django

Comment: @Daniel Roseman All the Stations are in remote place far far away from the server. They are having constrained network bandwidth and there will be network latency. I need to fetch data from each station for every 1 second. So I planned to have independent process for each station. So each process can fetch data from one station and it will log into Database

Comment: I second @DanielRoseman, you shouldn't be creating tables on the fly. You could create a new model called StationData or whatever, and have a foreign key to a Station Table.

Comment: @at14 I am new to django. Can you give some example or reference.